# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name? but how?

Tags: java, multithreading, cmd, runnable

So I was doing my assignment when I have to use my command prompt for this. I tried to look it up everywhere but I still don't understand how I get these error. Does anyone know what went wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/272fh.png)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\benny>cd C:\Users\benny\IdeaProjects\PA10\src\E22_7

C:\Users\benny\IdeaProjects\PA10\src\E22_7>javac WordCount.java

C:\Users\benny\IdeaProjects\PA10\src\E22_7>java WordCount file_one.txt file_two.txt
Error: Could not find or load main class WordCount
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: E22_7/WordCount (wrong name: WordCount)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm running it from where the file is. Should I run the code elsewhere?

Comment: Is the created **JAR** file located in `C:\Users\benny\IdeaProjects\PA10\src\E22_7`? If so, perhaps try: `java -jar WordCount.jar file_one.txt file_two.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you stuck `package E22_7;` at the top of that file.

In that case, go one directory up:

```
javac E22_7\WordCount.java
java E22_7.WordCount
```